# C program copy string without using strcpy() with enough memory

Tags: c, strcpy

I am trying to have this output:

```
Comparing results of concat and strcat ...
strcmp("Plain old stringTroy", "Plain old stringTroy") says: 0
```

The strcmp returns 0 if the two string arguments are identical. If the result is 0, then the concat behaves exactly like the library function strcat.

this is what I have for concat method.

```
#define MAXSIZE 32       
void concat(char dest[], char src[])                                        
{                                                                           
    int i=length(src);                                                          
    int j=0;                                                                    
    for(j; j<src[j] !='\0'; j++) {                                                                           
      dest[i+j] = src[j];                                                       
    }                                                                           
    dest[i+j] = '\0';                                                        
}
```

length method is:

```
 int length(char str[])                                                      
 {                                                                           
      // Add code here to return the length of the                              
      // string str without using the strlen function                           
      // Do not count the null character '\0'                                   
      // in computing the length of the string                                  
      int len=0;                                                                
      int i;                                                                    
      for(i=0;i<str[i];i++) {                                                    
          len++;                                                                  
      }                                                                         
      return len;                                                               
 }
```

This is my main

```
int main()                                                                  
{                                                                           
      // Variable declarations for all parts        
      char str2[] = "Troy";                                                                                                
      char str4[] = "Plain old string";                                         
      char str6[MAXSIZE];   
   // Part 6                                                                 
      printf("\n----- Part 6 -----\n");                                         
      // Make a copy of the destination string first, to be reused later        
      strcpy(str6, str4);                                                       
      concat(str4, str2);                                                       
      strcat(str6, str2);                                                       
      printf("Comparing results of concat and strcat ...\n");                   
      printf("strcmp(\"%s\", \"%s\") says: %d\n", 
             str4, str6, strcmp(str4, str6)
            );   

      return 0;                                                                 
}
```

This is my output when I run it:

```
----- Part 6 -----
Comparing results of concat and strcat ...
strcmp("PlaiTroy", "Plain old stringTroy") says: -1
```

The first string is not the same as the second string which is why I am getting a -1. My problem is in my concat method but I can't seem to understand why it won't execute well. Is it because of the spaces? Is 0 and '\0' not executing well?

Comment: `j<src[j] !='\0'` that's a strange condition. Isn't that just `src[j] !='\0'`

Comment: also in your len method `i<str[i]` ??? should be `for(i=0;str[i];i++)`

Comment: Have you tried printing the strings to see what they look like?

Comment: Take your debugger. Run the code line by line. See what it actually does. Check the contents of the strings. Think about the code. And see what @Jean-FrançoisFabre said about the biggest problem points.

Comment: The array `str4` have space for exactly 17 characters, including the terminator. Think about what happens in the `concat` function when you use `str4` as the destination string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can't find a C reference right now, but my tests in C++ on coliru are showing `char c = -127; int i = c; std::cout << i << std::endl;` outputting `-127`. So those statements appear to be different, at least in c++. (of course I agree that OP's is a bug)

Comment: @MillieSmith you don't have to convince _me_ that the code is wrong :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hahah fair enough :).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We also don't know if `MAXSIZE` is big enough for the result.

Comment: You need to read about memory management in C. What memory you own when you create strings on the stack (like you have) and how malloc and free work. Then you need to find your (other) bugs in concat. Jean has pointed out one of them, and following SomeProgrammerDude's advice should find another one for you.

Comment: I forgot to add that MAXSIZE is 32

Comment: Why the downvote? The is a complete question.

Comment: @alk I downvoted because I think that at a minimum OP should have shown that he knew the content of `str4` and `str6`. This is something you should know before asking why they are not equal.

Comment: in `concat()`, you start `i` at the wrong offset. It should be `i=length(dest)`, not `i=length(src)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The loop test in the `length` function is incorrect: instead of `i < str[i]`, it should be:

  ```
   for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  ```
- the same problem in the `concat` function. Change the loop to:

  ```
   for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++) {
  ```
- also in the `concat` function, `i` should be the length of `dst`, not that of `src`. You might use `len` instead of `i` for this variable.
- The array `str4` in function `main` does not have any space available at the end for `concat` to append anything. Define it with a larger size this way:

  ```
  char str4[MAXSIZE] = "Plain old string";
  ```

Here is the corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 32

void concat(char dest[], char src[]) {
    int len = length(dest);
    int j;
    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        dest[len + j] = src[j];
    }
    dest[len + j] = '\0';
}

int length(char str[]) {
    int len = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < str[i]; i++) {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main(void) {
    // Variable declarations for all parts
    char str2[MAXSIZE] = "Troy";
    char str4[MAXSIZE] = "Plain old string";
    char str6[MAXSIZE];
    // Part 6
    printf("\n----- Part 6 -----\n");
    // Make a copy of the destination string first, to be reused later
    strcpy(str6, str4);
    concat(str4, str2);
    strcat(str6, str2);
    printf("Comparing results of concat and strcat ...\n");
    printf("strcmp(\"%s\", \"%s\") says: %d\n",
           str4, str6, strcmp(str4, str6));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in both functions:

**`concat`**

```
for(j; j<src[j] !='\0'; j++) {
```

What is the for exit condition here?, `src[j] != '\0'` is enough.

```
dest[i+j] = src[j];
```

Here you add data with an offset of `i`, but I is the length of `src`, not `dst`.

So the corrected function could be:

```
void concat(char dest[], char src[])
{
    /* descriptive variable name */
    int len_dst = length(dst);
    int j=0;

    /* clear exit condition */
    for(; src[j] != '\0'; j++) { 
      dest[len_dst+j] = src[j];
    }
    dest[len_dst+j] = '\0';
}
```

**`length`**

```
for(i=0;i<str[i];i++) {
```

Same remark, what is this exit condition? `src[i] != '\0'` is enough

So the corrected function could be:

```
 int length(char str[])
 {
      int len=0;
      int i;
      /* clear exit condition */
      for ( i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
          len++;
      }
      return len;
 }
```

**`main`**

And warning in `main` function:

```
char str4[] = "Plain old string";
concat(str4, str2);  /* <- erases what is after str4 */
```

You do not have enough space to store result. Write something like:

```
char str2[] = "Troy";
char str4[MAXSIZE] = "Plain old string"; /* <-- reserve spaces after str4*/
/* ... */
concat(str4, str2);
```